# Script and Java: How can i say to Java to put the output file into a new folder?

Tags: java, json, shell, unix, cygwin

I have this code who takes a Bash file and run it, then it prints the proccess from the Bash in the console:

```
package main.java.com.reachforce.java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class RunScript {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            // Run the process

            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = run.exec("C:/cygwin64/bin/bash -c \\'/bin/tests/SatoriTest1.sh 04.10 C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\tests");
            p.waitFor();

            // Get the input stream
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

            // Read script execution results
            int i = 0;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while ( (i = is.read()) != -1)
                sb.append((char)i);

            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And the console after run it shows me:

> Test SatoriTest1 writing output to /SatoriTest1-output
>
> Now formatting imput file /inputfile
>
> Executing curl -k -v -i -X POST -d  --output /SatoriTest1-output
>   --header "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" /satori-service/validate
>
> End SatoriTest1.sh

I was trying to figure out where this "SatoriTest1-output" is created but... i can't find it.

This is the .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 

# First need to compute directory for sourcing additonal files 
DIR="$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE}" )/.." 
CURLDIR=`dirname "$(readlink -f "$BASH_SOURCE")"`
SCRIPTNAME="SatoriTest1"

# This script relies on the getconfig settings so calling now .
"${CURLDIR}/getmicroserviceconfig.sh"

# Calling the getmicroserviceconfig.sh function to get the configuration
getmicroserviceconfig

# Also the formatSatori.sh FORMATFILE="${OUTPATH}/formatSatori.sh"  
if [ -f "${FORMATFILE}" ]    then
      . "${FORMATFILE}"   
 fi

#
#  Usage ./SatoriTest1.sh
#
# Testing /satori-service: POSTs a new address for validation
#
# Note: using -k to avoid certificate foof 
#
# Depends on: 001-login test (to get a successful login w/security token)

# SatoriTest1: /satori-service/validate: Satori address validation test
#Expect this to submit an address to Satori address validation service
#

THISTEST="SatoriTest1.sh"

APIPATH="satori-service/validate" FULLURL="${WEBSERVICEURL}/${APIPATH}" OUTPUTFILENAME="${OUTPATH}/SatoriTest1-output"

echo "Test $SCRIPTNAME writing output to ${OUTPUTFILENAME}"

NEWSATORIFILE="${OUTPATH}/inputfile"

echo "Now formatting imput file ${NEWSATORIFILE}"

formatSatori "${NEWSATORIFILE}"

NEWSATORIREQ=$newsatorireq

echo ${NEWSATORIREQ} > "${OUTPATH}/${OUTPUTFILENAME}.json"

# 
# Now make the API calls using curl 
#


# Calling POST with inputfile 
echo "Executing curl -k -v -i -X POST -d ${NEWSATORIREQ} --output ${OUTPUTFILENAME} --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"Accept:application/json\" ${FULLURL}" curl -k
-v -i -X POST -d "${NEWSATORIREQ}" --output "${OUTPUTFILENAME}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" "${FULLURL}"

echo "End ${THISTEST}"
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

Your input and output file path are constructed from OUTPATH which is undefined in the script. Hence,  OUTPUTFILENAME="${OUTPATH}/SatoriTest1-output" has become "/SatoriTest1-output".

Check for output file at root i.e, / or Initialize OUTPATH and give a try.